# MapThread to Spheres with various colours

Tags: graphics3d

I have these two lists

```
xyz={{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 
  1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}}

color={GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.5], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], GrayLevel[0.5], 
 GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.5], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}
```

I need to use this function `Graphics3D[{*Green*, Sphere[]}]` to plot each sphere with coordinates from `xyz` list and colour from `col` list.

by applying `MapThread[]`.

Comment: `Graphics3D[{dfhgkjdfhg, MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2]} &, {col, xyz}]}]`

Comment: Just an added detail: the colors will look more natural if you add `Lighting -> "Neutral"` at the end of `Graphics` (since I assume the true colors are important to you).

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
Graphics3D[MapThread[{#1, Sphere@#2} &, {color, xyz}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, if you want to avoid the hassle of `MapThread[]`: `{color, Sphere /@ xyz} // Transpose // Graphics3D`

Comment: Got it, Thanks for care.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `MapThread` you could use `Map` (`/@`) and `Thread`.

```
Graphics3D @ Thread @ {color, Sphere /@ xyz}
```

Or `Map` and `Riffle`:

```
Graphics3D @ Riffle[color, Sphere /@ xyz]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why the down-vote?